# Factoring 3 variable Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, factoring

Factor $ab^3 - a^3 b + bc^3 - b^3 c + ca^3 - c^3a$.

I have tried to pug in values that would equal zero and possibly make use of the multivariable factor theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$$ab^3 - a^3 b + bc^3 - b^3 c + ca^3 - c^3a=$$
$$ab(b-a)(b+a)+c^3(b-a)-c(b^3-a^3)=$$
$$=(b-a)(a^2b+b^2a+c^3-b^2c-abc-a^2c)=$$
$$=(b-a)(a^2(b-c)+ab(b-c)-c(b^2-c^2))=$$
$$=(b-a)(b-c)(a^2+ab-bc-c^2)=$$
$$=(b-a)(b-c)((a-c)(a+c)+b(a-c))=$$
$$=(b-a)(b-c)(a-c)(a+b+c).$$

Comment: Thank You so much!!

Comment: @fds-mqdwqmqkdwl You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$$(a+b+c)( a -b) (b-c)(c-a)  $$

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? f = -1 * (a+b+c)* ( a -b)* (b-c)*(c-a) 
%1 = (b - c)*a^3 + (-b^3 + c^3)*a + (c*b^3 - c^3*b)
? -f
%2 = (-b + c)*a^3 + (b^3 - c^3)*a + (-c*b^3 + c^3*b)
```

> Factor $ab^3 - a^3 b + bc^3 - b^3 c + ca^3 - c^3a$.

Comment: Thank You! Can you tell me the steps?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  That was the reason I needed to put a minus sign in front.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg evidently the extra minus sign was never needed.